# Is this unstable VBA Timer behavior real or am I doing something wrong

Tags: excel, vba, timer, performancecounter

I have seen some strange behavior for VBA Timer function which suggests it can have sudden changes in output of up to 250 milliseconds, and I would like to understand this since I use it often in my VBA code.  Is this even possible? Pls note that this is my first post to StackOverflow and I am not a professional programmer.

My research of timers says TIMER returns the number of fractional seconds since midnight, updated every few milliseconds depending on your PC environment.  So for a period of a few milliseconds it returns the same value, and then jumps to the next value when it is reset to current seconds past midnight.  I created a test code using  QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter  (QPFC) to compare time intervals measured by TIMER and QPFC to better understand this behavious.
My code sets a start time using TIMER and QPFC and runs a loop to look at the difference in elapsed milliseconds from the start time. Much to my surprise I see the occasional huge jumps in TIMER time.  The first image shows multiple jumps, max about 300mSec, when my Gigabyte Aero is running on battery but I see similar behavior when plugged in, and on my Surface Pro 4.

Image of output from Code:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDDuQ.png

The output shows that for my machine often there is 7.8 mSec update period for Timer as you can see in column A.  I have seen many different multiples of 7.8 (mostly 7.8/N values, mostly I see 3.9mSec).  But suddenly there can be a big jump in difference in elapsed time between the two timers that persists until the next jump in timer differences.  Sometimes it takes several hours of looping to see the jump, but often I see it in less than a minute.  I have run the same code on another multicore PC and see the same feature.  Spikes in the difference in timers I can understand (PC gets busy elsewhere between timer calls) but not these steps. It runs until there is a preselected delta between timers, or end of the allow run time if there are no large steps.

The test code is at the end of this question, it needs a workbook open with a worksheet called “Timer”, and will populate the sheet with the headings, data, analysis, graph shown above to facilitate review. I “read” the TIMER before and after the QPFC timer to help diagnose the issue.  Obviously if the PC decides that other activity is higher priority than this test code between the two TIMER queries, the difference between the two can take a big jump for one loop, but then should go back to the usual range of deltas between the two measured elapsed times.  I.e. a spike in timer difference, not a permanent timer difference. The timing information suggests it is TIMER that is jumping not QPFC.

I added a check on how long the two timer calls take, TIMER is about 60 nSec, QPFC is about 900 nSec on my machine.  I turned off time resets in Date and Time settings (not in VBA but in Windows). I see the jumps even if I use Task Manager to set the Excel affinity to one CPU.

Is my test code OK?  Am I interpreting the data correctly?  How can “time since midnight” change like this?

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LongLong) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LongLong) As Long
Private ll_Counter As LongLong
Private dFrequency As Double
'just put all variables where they can be used throughout module, not good practice but makes this test code easy to write
Dim dTimer1 As Double, dTimer2 As Double, dMaxDelta As Double, dLL_TimerDelta As Double, dTotalTime As Double
Dim dTimerStart As Double, dLL_TimerStart As Double, dTimer1Delta As Double, dTimer2Delta As Double, dMaxMinutes As Double
Dim iRow As Long, idTimerNothing As Long, iNothing As Long
Dim iLoops As Long, iReUse As Long

Sub Test_LongLongTimer()   'needs an open workbook with sheet names "Timer"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Worksheets("Timer").Select
    SetUpWorksheet
Call SetFrequency  'set the frequency for QPFC timer
dTotalTime = 0#
dMaxDelta = 0#
dTimerStart = Timer
dLL_TimerStart = LL_Timer
dMaxMinutes = 5#

Do While dMaxDelta < 10 And dTotalTime < (dMaxMinutes * 60# * 1000#)  'stops the loop when the TIMER to QPFC timer difference exceeds dMaxDelta or time is longer than dMaxMinutes
        iRow = 2
        iLoops = 10000
        For iReUse = 2 To iLoops + 1  'allow for header row in top row   when saving data, saves every 100th calc
                            'read timers
                            dTimer1Delta = (Timer - dTimerStart) * 1000# 'convert to milliseconds
                            dLL_TimerDelta = (LL_Timer - dLL_TimerStart) * 1000# 'convert to milliseconds
                            dTimer2Delta = (Timer - dTimerStart) * 1000# 'convert to milliseconds
                            SaveTimers 'save timers and analysis functions
                            
                            For iNothing = 1 To 1 'add some extra delay before next comparisons to vary total time, change value as desired
                                DoEvents
                            Next iNothing
                            
                           Worksheets("Timer").Range("A" & iRow & ":K" & iRow).Calculate
                            If Abs(Worksheets("Timer").Range("I" & iRow).Value) > dMaxDelta Then dMaxDelta = Abs(Worksheets("Timer").Range("I" & iRow).Value)
                            dTotalTime = dTimer2Delta
                            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next iReUse
        Application.Calculate
        iRow = 2
Loop
'check time for LL_Timer function call, my system gives about 900 nanoseconds
        dTimerStart = Timer
        iLoops = 1000000
        For iReUse = 1 To iLoops
                dLL_TimerStart = LL_Timer
        Next iReUse
        dTimerStart = ((Timer - dTimerStart) / iLoops) * 1000000000# 'convert to NanoSeconds
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("P1").Value2 = "MY TIMER Avrg NanoSeconds per LL_Timer call"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("P2").Value2 = dTimerStart
 'check time for VBA  timer function call, my system gives about 65 nanoseconds
        dTimerStart = Timer
        iLoops = 1000000
        For iReUse = 1 To iLoops
                dLL_TimerStart = Timer
        Next iReUse
        dTimerStart = ((Timer - dTimerStart) / iLoops) * 1000000000# 'convert to NanoSeconds
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("P3").Value2 = "VBA TIMER Avrg NanoSeconds per Timer call"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("P4").Value2 = dTimerStart
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("p:p").ColumnWidth = 50
        With Worksheets("Timer").Range("A:P")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = True
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
                .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0_);[Red](#,##0.0)"
        End With

        Call AddChart
End Sub
Function LL_Timer() 'Seconds
    QueryPerformanceCounter ll_Counter
    LL_Timer = CDbl(ll_Counter) / dFrequency
End Function

Private Sub SetFrequency()
Dim PerfFrequency As LongLong
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    dFrequency = CDbl(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Sub AddChart()
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
For Each ChtObj In Worksheets("Timer").ChartObjects
        ChtObj.Delete
Next ChtObj

    Range("H3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Timer!$C$2:$C$1001")
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "TimerDelta"
       With ActiveChart.Parent
                .Width = 15 * 72 '500  ' resize   72 pnts per inch
                .Height = 3 * 72 '500  ' resize   72 pnts per inch
                .Top = 105 ' reposition
                .Left = 125 'reposition
     End With
Dim ax As Axis
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 16
        .TickLabels.Font.Bold = True
        .Crosses = xlMaximum
End With
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 16
        .TickLabels.Font.Bold = True
End With
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select  'funny stuff re bad display, fix by moving around
Range("C25").Select

End Sub
Sub SetUpWorksheet()
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("A2:K1000000").ClearContents
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("A1").Value2 = "dTimer1 (mSec)"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("B1").Value2 = "dMyTimer (mSEC)"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("C1").Value2 = "dTimer2 (mSEC)"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("D1").Value2 = "Delta, Timer1 to previous"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("E1").Value2 = "Delta, dMyTimer to previous, mSec"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("F1").Value2 = "Delta, Timer2 to previous"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("G1").Value2 = "Delta, Timer2 to dMyTimer"
         Worksheets("Timer").Range("H1").Value2 = "Delta, dMyTimer to Timer1"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("I1").Value2 = "Delta of LL-T1 delta to previous delta"  'delta of column H
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("J1").Value2 = "QueryPerformanceCounter"
        Worksheets("Timer").Range("K1").Value2 = "QueryPerformanceCounter Delta To Previous"
End Sub
Sub SaveTimers()
                            Worksheets("Timer").Range("A" & iRow).Value = dTimer1Delta
                            Worksheets("Timer").Range("B" & iRow).Value = dLL_TimerDelta
                            Worksheets("Timer").Range("C" & iRow).Value2 = dTimer2Delta
                            Worksheets("Timer").Range("J" & iRow).Formula = ll_Counter
                            If iRow > 2 Then
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("D" & iRow).Value = "=(A" & iRow & "-A" & (iRow - 1) & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("E" & iRow).Value = "=(B" & iRow & "-B" & (iRow - 1) & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("F" & iRow).Value = "=(C" & iRow & "-C" & (iRow - 1) & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("G" & iRow).Value = "=(C" & iRow & "-B" & iRow & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("H" & iRow).Value = "=(B" & iRow & "-A" & iRow & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("I" & iRow).Value = "=(H" & iRow & "-H" & (iRow - 1) & ")"
                                        Worksheets("Timer").Range("K" & iRow).Value = "=(J" & iRow & "-J" & (iRow - 1) & ")"
                            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA's Timer internally uses the Win32 API [SetTimer()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), which in turn fires the [WM_TIMER event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer). And this is, quote: _"The WM_TIMER message is **a low-priority message**. The GetMessage and PeekMessage functions post this message only when no other higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue."_ So, works as intended (by MS). See also [this article](http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/timer-comparison-tests/4594552971) about timers.

Comment: I hope I am putting this reply to answer in the right place.

Comment: I blew that comment, sorry. I'm a Newbie.  Thanks, Hel.  I think you say:  Timer update can be delayed due to the events that  happen to get it updated.  But what I am seeing is not a delay in Timer update but a totally new Timer value, a step function in number of fractional seconds since midnight.  For example, one run loop shows QPFC elapsed time of 1.7 msec, but TIMER jumps ahead 247 msec and stays ahead. Sometimes TIMER jumps BACK in time to show an earlier (permanent) time.  If you only look at averages and standard deviations you will not see these outliers.

Comment: I see. And I admit that I didn't fully understand your question the first time around. Though I still think the underlaying Win32 API causes the behavior you're experiencing. So API experts might be better suited to answer your question. That said, have you compared it with a timer class like [this one](https://classicvb.net/samples/TimerObj/)?